# Rails 3 - validating one of two fields has been completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I'm writing a Rails app to manage a series of banners along the top of our website; each one should link either to a URL provided by the editor, or a specific product selected from a drop-down list.

I'd like to put some kind of validation in the model, for consistency with other checks, that makes sure one (but not both) of the fields (product ID or URL) has been provided when saving.

Is there a `validates`-type way to check this, or will I have to put this check somewhere in the controller instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a pretty straight validation in the model:

```
validate :check_consistency

def check_consistency
  if product_id.blank? and url.blank?
   #one at least must be filled in, add a custom error message
   return false
  elsif !product_id.blank? and !url.blank?
   #both can't be filled in, add custom error message
   return false
  else
   return true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this is more or less it, although your elsif isn't quite right. It should be `elsif (!product_id.blank? and !url.blank?)`  Otherwise, it's validating neatly without having to write my own custom validators (which I was afraid of).

Answer (score 6):

Similar answer to above but this is just an exclusive or and if else statements aren't needed

```
validate :check_consistency
def check consistency
  errors.add(:base, 'message') if product_id.blank? ^ url.blank?
end
```

Comment: Not only is this is a cleaner version of the accepted answer, but providing a specific error message is more useful than simply returning false